# Trying to replace pattern _1_ with _01_ but its not working

Tags: substitute, search-replace

I am using Vim version 9.0.1280.

The search and replace command I am using is -

```
:%s/\(_\)\([1-9]\{1\}\)\(_\)/_0\1_/gc
```

When I run this vim offers to replace `_1_` with `_0\1_`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The string that's offered is before `\1` is expanded to "1" so after accepting, it should be fine (except that your substitution produces "_0\_\_" in the end)

Comment: Isn't `\1` referring to `\(_\)` part? And `\2` to `\([1-9]\{1\}\)` part…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
:%s/\(_\)\([1-9]\{1\}\)\(_\)/_0\2_/gc
```

Or more compact:

```
:%s/_\zs\d\{1\}\ze_/0&/gc
```

I limit the part of the regular expression I want to replace with `\zs` and `\ze` and I can use the full pattern `\0` replacement expression.

Or as @gildux mention:

```
:%s/\v_(\d{1})_/_0\1_/gc
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked

Comment: I type `\0` as `&`, but either work

Comment: Good idea, one character less ;-)

Comment: It's possible to use `\1` by avoiding useless grouping in search (at least it appears so to me without knowing further context.) So `:%s/_\([1-9]\{1\}\)_/_0\1_/gc` witch can be shorten under Vim to `:%s/_\(\d\+\)_/_0\1_/gc`

Answer (score 1):

When Vim says, `replace with _0\1_ ...`, it hasn't replaced the `\1` you typed with the first group yet.

The first group in your expression is `\(_\)`, so the resulting text *after* the substitution is `_0__`.

You want the matched number which is the *second* group. So to fix your original regexp, just use `\2` instead of `\1`:

```
:%s/\(_\)\([1-9]\{1\}\)\(_\)/_0\2_/gc
```

However as [gildux points out](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/40167/trying-to-replace-pattern-1-with-01-but-its-not-working#comment73625_40168), there's no need to create groups for the underscores. You can just use a single group for the bit you actually want to re-use:

```
:%s/_\([1-9]\)_/_0\1_/gc
                          " The search pattern is:
    _                     " an underscore followed by:
     \(     \)            " group \1, containing
       [1-9]              " a non-zero digit
              _           " followed by another underscore
```

Note that I've also removed the `\{1\}` from your original query. `[1-9]` already matches one atom, so specifying you want to match one of them doesn't make much sense in this context! (Perhaps your example is slimmed down from your real use-case.)